# Tkinter DPI bug depends on how import is entered?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, highdpi

I have a weird question. In essence: why does the way I *enter* the pyplot `import` line into iPython influence my plot?!

Try this (on Windows 10):

- Use a high-DPI main monitor set to 200%
- Start a fresh iPython console
- Enter the three blocks of code below one by one, using any of these ways for any block:

  1. just **typing**, *OR*
  2. **pasting**: pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, *OR*
  3. pasting: clicking the right **mouse button**, *OR*
  4. pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> to get it from **history**
- To execute each block, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Check whether the whole axis is visible
- Close iPython and try again

The minimal reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from ctypes import windll
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)
fig = plt.figure()
w = fig.canvas.manager.window
print(w.winfo_screenwidth(), w.winfo_screenheight())
w.wm_geometry('1600x800+60+0')
fig.canvas.flush_events()
plt.plot(1, 'x')
plt.show(block=False)
```

Now the result depends on *how* the first two blocks have been entered. If one or both of them used option 1 or 2, an incorrect monitor size is reported (1920x1080), but I do get a 'correct' plot (with tiny fonts):
[image: options 1 and 2]

If both import lines have been entered using option 3 or 4 however, the reported monitor size is correct (3840x2160), but I get incorrectly sized/zoomed plots (with normal font size):
[image: options 3 and 4]

The behavior depends on how `import` lines (or the 'run script' they are in) are *entered*!? Not how they are *run*, that's just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Any idea what causes this? Or how to fix it? Other than remembering to always do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead of history or right click...
Is this a bug I can report somewhere?

Changing the window size manually a bit afterwards makes the axis fit inside the window. But I would like to script it. And the manual resize does not fix all differences: options 1 and 2 keep using tiny fonts.

Explicitly resetting `SetProcessDpiAwareness(0)` prevents the issue (1 and 2 keep it): monitor reported as 1920x1080, axes fit inside figure, but a larger window and normal size fonts.

Specifying `dpi=192` (or something) explicitly with `plt.figure()` does not help or change anything.

The used backend is the **TkAgg** Windows default. The exact same happens with **TkCairo**. The **WxAgg** and **QtAgg** alternatives work ok, using `window.SetClientSize(1600, 800)` resp. `manager.resize(1600, 800)` (they work like `SetProcessDpiAwareness(0)`). So I guess the issue is specific to `tkinter`.

Using python.exe (instead of ipython.exe) always shows the *in*correct version. AFAICS I have not changed the High DPI compatibility settings for iPython.

Comment: Just a wild guess, have you tried commenting out `flush_events` ?

Comment: `dpi`-related things are remarkably painful in matplotlib in general. The best strategy tends to be finding a way to get what you need, and not to deviate from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Almost* all differences are gone when I do this:

```
fig.dpi = windll.user32.GetDpiForWindow(w.winfo_id()) / 0.96
```

This leaves `w.winfo_screenwidth/height()` halved and small tool buttons when using options 1 and 2. But the window is 1600 pixels wide as specified (758 resp. 728 high, due to the button bar), fonts are readable (200% as configured in Windows) and the axes fit inside the figure.

I must remember *not* to use `dpi=` with `plt.figure()`, because that messes things up again.

I'm still curious where the difference comes from, but this way I can use the default Tk backend without issues.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you end up with the same result when just setting the dpi awareness after the window has been created?

Comment: @Thingamabobs Same result.